# I need to rewrite 2 urls in htaccess to different page. Both urls start with same name but one with single parameter and the other with 2 parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have 2 dynamic urls

http://localhost:8080/overseas/cost/cancer
and
http://localhost:8080/overseas/cost/cancer/cancer-treatment

structure is like user will click on any department (cancer, cardiology, dental etc) the url will be first url written above and in that particular department there are procedures under that department which again has a url which is second url written above.
I need to maintain the url perfectly for SEO (meaning first "cost" then "department" and then "procedure")

my htaccess code is

```
RewriteRule ^cost/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ department.php?type=dept&dept=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cost/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ department.php?type=dept&dept=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^cost/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ procedure.php?type=spe&dept=$1&spe=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^cost/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ procedure.php?type=spe&dept=$1&spe=$2 [L]
```

Problem with htaccess is that the second procedure rewrite rule is not working and always first department rewrite url is only working for both the urls.

I did not find any answers related to this topic over the internet. Can anybody help
thanks

Comment: Turn the order around. Rule-of-thumb: Always handle the more specific cases first, the less specific ones later.

Comment: FYI: Both your "second versions" of these patterns, ending in `/`, will still allow for any arbitrary stuff _after_ that slash. If you want an option slash at the end - then you should be using _one_ rule, that allows for an optional slash at the end, with `/?$`

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9-/]` - that character group explicitly contains the / as well. If you want to use it to only match parts that _don't_ contain any slashes (and you probably don't, with the given examples), that should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @CBroe. I placed the less specific case later and it worked. Thanks a lot